# Invalid node context using ContextAwarePluginInterface

Tags: blocks

I am trying to create a block in Drupal 8 that would help me to show an image using a link given in a certain content type link. I tought it would be useful to use the ContextAwarePluginInterface.

I tried a simple example:

```
namespace Drupal\image_view\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContextAwarePluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Currently this is a block with a simple text
 * 
 * @Block(
 *  id = "image_view_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Link to Image"),
 *  context = {
 *      "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node")
 *  }
 * )
 */
class LinkToImageBlock extends BlockBase implements ContextAwarePluginInterface{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build() {
        $context = $this->getContextValue("node");
        return [
            '#markup' => $this->t('Simple Block text. This will be an image, ha ha!'),
        ];
    }
}
```

If I comment the following line everything works fine.

```
$context = $this->getContextValue("node");
```

What would cause this? I tried to look it up but didn't find any answers.

Comment: Then the node context doesn't exist. In blocks a missing context value doesn't cause an error, the block just denies access.

Comment: I understand. This makes sense. Do you have any idea on how I could acomplish what I intend to do (show image using url)

Comment: This should work fine, but only on a node page. Then $context contains the node and you can check the content type and get the link from the node.

Comment: So, if I add the block in my content type (for example by using layout builder), would I, then, be on a correct node page?